# Drupal: Auto number field for content-type with starting value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields, drupal-content-types

I need a field which autonumbers my content-type, but starts at some value like 2000. I tried Serial Field and Computed Field. Couldn`t figure out how to do it. The number (using Serial Field) does automatically increment, but I cannot define a starting number.

Is there anyway to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using **Computed Field**.
Add a computed field to your content type and set the data type to be integer. In the Computed Field (PHP) textarea this code will work for you:

```
if (empty($entity_field[0]['value'])) {
  $count = db_select('node')->fields('node')->condition('type', $entity->type)->execute()->rowCount();
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = $count + 2000;
}
```

This checks if a value for this field is already set for this node and if not - it gets the total number of nodes of this content type, adds a constant (2000 in this example) and sets the result as the value for your field.

Answer (score 2):

We use custom auto-numbers on several custom record types in our Drupal 6 system (the following should also work for Drupal 7). To make it work, we implemented a rule using the Rules module that fires upon saving the record.

The rule runs ON event *After saving content* and should verify that you're saving the content type you're interested in. (For example, if you're auto numbering Widgets, add an IF for *Content type is Widget*.

For your actions, put an *Populate created content's 'custom_number' field* action on the rule (where 'custom_number' is your auto-number field), and follow this example:

```
$number = db_result(db_query(
    "SELECT MAX(field_custom_number_value) FROM {content_type_widget}"));

if(empty($number) || $number < 200) { // Replace 200 with your starting value
    $number = 200;
} else {
    $number++;
}

return array( 0 => array('value' => $number) );
```

Every time you save a new widget, the system runs a query to find the max custom_number already assigned. If none are assigned, or a number less than 200 is assigned, the system will assign 200; otherwise, it will assign 1 more than the current max number assigned.

If you wanted to, you could also add a line of debug code to add a watchdog line or other debug event in the event that a number less than your desired minimum is discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The **Serial Module** generates a table whose name is **serial_bundlename_fieldname** i.e. If you have added a field name '**field_job_id**' for bundle '**Jobs**' then a table '**serial_jobs_field_job_id**' will be created.

The table contains 2 fields '**sid**' and '**nid**'
'**sid**' is auto increment field.

You can use a tool like phpMyAdmin and execute the following query

ALTER TABLE  `serial_jobs_field_job_id` AUTO_INCREMENT =2000;

This should possibly set the starting value for autoincrement field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I used the computed module instead